# rdesktop can't change color depth (Model B+, Stretch)

Tags: raspbian-stretch, rdp

I'm on a Raspberry Pi model B+.
I'm running Raspbian-Lite 9 Jesse.
My super lightweight GUI is xorg + fluxbox.

The rdesktop command works great - EXCEPT...

All of these commands give me the same color depth (24). I can't reduce the color depth to 8. I actually can't get any color depth except for 24.

```
rdesktop -u user@dnsdomain.com -p password -f -a 8  win10propc
rdesktop -u user@dnsdomain.com -p password -f -a 16 win10propc
rdesktop -u user@dnsdomain.com -p password -f -a 24 win10propc
rdesktop -u user@dnsdomain.com -p password -f -a 32 win10propc
```

Any ideas why rdesktop is just simply ignoring my color depth argument?

Answer (score 3):

> -a
>
> Sets the colour depth for the connection (8, 15, 16 or 24). More than 8 bpp are only supported when connecting to Windows XP (up to 16 bpp) or newer. **Note that the colour depth may also be limited by the server configuration.** The default value is the depth of the root window.

It seems that the server you're using is not offering any other depths besides 24 bpp.

Comment: Awesome. I'll check the server and update here.

Comment: Anybody know how to find this setting on Win10 Pro?

Comment: On Win 10 Pro. I changed the Group Policy setting “Computer Configuration” > “Administrative Templates” > “Windows Components” > “Remote Desktop Services” > “Remote Desktop Session Host“ > "Remote Session Environment" > "Limit maximum color depth" > Enabled, 16 bit color depth. But I'm still not connecting at that color depth.